# Trading View Pine Editor Compilation Error

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm getting the following error, but I'm confused:

`Compilation error. Script could not be translated from: |B|for i = 1 to`

Below is the script I'm running

```
// Find cup and handle formations and mark breakout point

study("Cup and Handle")

// User inputs
handleLength = input(5, minval=1, maxval=50)
minCupDepth = input(5, minval=1, maxval=50)
maxCupDepth = input(20, minval=1, maxval=100)

// Find local minima (bottom of cup)
bottom = low
for i = 1 to handleLength
    bottom := min(bottom, low[i])

// Calculate depth of cup
depth = high - bottom

// Check if cup meets criteria
isCup = depth > minCupDepth and depth < maxCupDepth

// Find handle high (local maxima within handleLength bars of cup bottom)
handleHigh = bottom
for i = 1 to handleLength
    handleHigh := max(handleHigh, high[i])

// Find handle low (local minima within handleLength bars of cup bottom)
handleLow = bottom
for i = 1 to handleLength
    handleLow := min(handleLow, low[i])

// Check if handle meets criteria
isHandle = handleHigh > bottom and handleLow < bottom

// Mark breakout point
breakout = na
if isCup and isHandle
    breakout = bottom

// Plot results
plot(breakout, color=red, linewidth=3)
```

Any help here would be SO appreciated!!

I'm very new to this and don't know where to begin troubleshooting... I'm first confused on what the "|B|" means as it's not part of the script.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

`for` keyword was introduced starting from `v2`. When you don't have a version declaration, the compiler will assume that it is `v1`.

Add the below statement to your code.

```
//@version=2
```